# Multi-Cursor Not Working on Certain Computers (Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, cursor

I teach Java at the HS level and we work in a lab with 30 or so computers. We use Netbeans as our IDE.

I am noticing a weird phenomenon that I don't understand:
On computers running the x86 version of Windows, the multi-cursor tools works in Netbeans.

However, in x64 the `ctrl + shift + click` just highlights a block of text.

I have checked the control mapping and searched for weeks and haven't been able to solve this issue.

Comment: What version of NB? Are you using the latest Apache NetBeans 10? Or on an older 8.x version?

Comment: This is with 8.2

Comment: Also, there are other features that don't work on this version: the tack buttons for watches (in Debugger) are not there, so it is impossible to use them at all.

Comment: I have asked some SO Netbeans questions and received good answers but it might be best to use the Netbeans users mailing list. I've found NB 10.x to be acceptable (some of the transitional issues seem to have settled and getting things set up is now reasonable). My guess is that crtrl+shift+click is somehow being intercepted on those machines (certainly there are ways to test, including writing a program of your own). I only have access to Linux machines, so am unable to check Windows related issues. Both NB 8.2 and 10.0 behave as expected regarding the multi cursor, on my local.